Asymptotic dynamics under a linear iteration
I am trying to find the long time behaviour under the following iterative dynamics. $P_t(n)$, for each time step $t$ is a function from non negative integers $n$ to real numbers.
$P_{t=0}=\delta_{n0}$
$P$ at the next time step $t+1$ is given by
$P_{t+1}(0)=n^2 (P_t(1)+\frac{1}{4} P_0)$ for $n=0$ and
$P_{t+1}(n)= n^2 (P_t(n+1)+P_t(n-1)+\frac{1}{4} P_t(n))$ for $n>0$.
I numerically simulated the evolution of $P$. In the long time limit has the form
$P_t(n)=N_t\exp\left[- \frac{(n-vt)^2}{2\sigma^2 t}\right]$
where $v$ and $\sigma^2$ were $\approx 0.73$ and $\approx 0.27$ from numerical fits. The above solution seems to be nearly exact at large $t$ based on my numerical tests.
Is there a way to show this asymptotic form of the solution that I discovered from numerics ?
